# Basecamp 3 API for reports/progress

Tags: basecamp

Basecamp's website has the feature to check the latest activity.

The URL: 3.basecamp.com/{id}/reports/progress

I'm interested in exploring more of this data and integrating it into our internal company apps.

I have checked [bc3-api](https://github.com/basecamp/bc3-api) but didn't find any information about it.
Is there any information about how to get that data? or any plan about how long it would be implemented as the API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I asked this question directly to Basecamp and they mentioned that "right now that's not something that's possible with the API."